# What is the equivalent in tensorflow 2.x of Conv2D by a Pythorch version with padding=0 or 1?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

How can i write this Conv2D of Pythorch :

```
self.c7=nn.Conv2d(256,512,kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=0)
```

and

```
  self.c8=nn.Conv2d(512,256,kernel_size=3,stride=1, padding=1)
```

In tensorflow i just have 'same' or 'valid'...

```
x=layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1),padding='same',activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(x)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, ```padding=0``` is the same of ```valid```. For custom padding look at ```tf.pad```.

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow `padding='valid'` means no padding. Where as `padding='same'` results in padding with zeros evenly to the left/right or up/down of the input such that output has the same height/width dimension as the input. For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#args).